# Best way to merge multiple STL containers, removing duplicate elements?

Tags: c++, stl

I have two STL containers that I want to merge, removing any elements that appear more than once.  For example:

```
typedef std::list<int> container;
container c1;
container c2;

c1.push_back(1);
c1.push_back(2);
c1.push_back(3);

c2.push_back(2);
c2.push_back(3);
c2.push_back(4);

container c3 = unique_merge(c1, c2);
// c3 now contains the following 4 elements:
//   1, 2, 3, 4
```

std::unique seems to be for adjacent elements only, and in my case the containers could be in any order.  I could do some **std::set** trickery I guess:

```
container unique_merge(const container& c1, const container& c2)
{
    std::set<container::value_type> s;
    BOOST_FOREACH(const container::value_type& val, c1)
        s.insert(val);
    BOOST_FOREACH(const container::value_type& val, c2)
        s.insert(val);
    return container(s.begin(), s.end());
}
```

Is there a better way or have I missed something bleeding obvious?

Comment: If you ask for something "bleeding obvious", your implementation is good enough for moust cases. But a better algorithm does exist, at the cost of O(N * log(M)), where N is the total number of elements in all containers, and M is the number of containers. The code is not trivial, I'll write later when I have time.

Comment: @RnMss Really? Can you post an answer? ...

Comment: @user202729 omg It was 2014...

Comment: @user202729 Now I'm not sure about it. I think ... , judged by what I wrote, that ... maybe ... at that time I thought that each container are already sorted, but the number of containers could be a larger number (like 1000 or more).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an unordered lists, your set trick is probably one of the best.  It each insert should be O(log n), with N inserts required, and traversing will be O(n), giving you O(N*log n).
The other option is to run std::sort on each list individually and then walk through them in parallel using [std::set_union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a20tb7e2.aspx), which removes duplicates for you.  This will also be O(n*log n), so if you're worried about performance, you'll have to profile.  If you're not, do whichever makes more sense to you.

Edit:
`set_union` will only work if there are no duplicates in the original lists, otherwise you'll have to go with `sort`, `merge`, `unique` and `erase`.  The big O performance is still the same, with the same caveats about profiling.

```
template <typename container>
container unique_merge(container c1, container c2)
{
    std::sort(c1.begin(), c1.end());
    std::sort(c2.begin(), c2.end());
    container mergeTarget;
    std::merge(c1.begin(), c1.end(), c2.begin(), c2.end(), 
        std::insert_iterator(mergeTarget, mergeTarget.end())
    );
    std::erase(
        std::unique(mergeTarget.begin(), mergeTarget.end()), 
        mergeTarget.end()
    );

    return mergeTarget;
}
```

Comment: According to the specification for std::set_union: If there are duplicate elements in the two ranges, R1 and R2, say V occurs N times in R1 and M times in R2, the result of std::set_union will contain max(N, M) instances of V. So unless N<=1 and M<=1 it's not a correct solution.

Comment: That's what I get for not test-compiling it.

Answer (score 4):

You are going to need to either sort (either explicitly, or implicitly via a sorted container like set).

There is a common idiom using std::sort/std::unique/std::erase to get unique elements in a container.

So create a container with the contents of c1, append the contents of c2, then sort, move unique elements to the end, and erase them. Something like this:

```
container c(c1.begin(), c1.end());
c.insert(c.end(), c2.begin(), c2.end());
std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
c.erase(std::unique(c.begin(), c.end()), c.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [std::set_union algorithm](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union) from the STL.  You'll need to sort your input lists first though -- or create copies of your input lists, sort them, then use std::set_union.