# Efficient way to search and find elements in one vector from the other vector?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, iterator, find

I have two `std::vector<long>`s. One has 5 elements and the other has 100 elements. I want to compare elements from the smaller vector with the larger vector, and if an element is not found in the larger vector I want to push it back into the larger vector. I have my code here:

```
vector<long> Matvec, MatTempVec;
//assume Matvec has 5 elements and MatTempvec has 100 elements.

vector<long>::iterator It1;
for (auto it = Matvec.begin(); it != Matvec.end(); it++)
{
    It1 = find(MatTempVec.begin(), MatTempVec.end(), it);
    if (It1 != MatTempVec.end())
        MatTempVec.push_back(*it);
}
```

Suggest me an efficient way for this search and find, other than what I have done above.

Comment: Are the data in either or both vectors sorted?

Comment: 5×100=500. Computers nowadays can do that in <1µs. Show your actual problem please.

Comment: data in both vectors are not sorted

Comment: Should be using a b-tree data-structure or something else sorted so you can index the big list in logarithmic time, that's what a database does, but with 100 elements, it's hardly a concern.

Comment: you probably need `std::set`, not `std::vector`

Comment: The vector size may increase in both the vectors to millions...Is this method efficient for handling millions of data?Or suggest me other methods!!

Comment: Unless you can change the way the data are stored, and that doesn't cause performance issues elsewhere, instinct suggest to me that the way you have it is pretty optimal, given that one of the vectors is very short. Be careful not to *invalidate* iterators though.

Comment: google b-tree data-structures and bloom-filters. CassandraDB uses bloom-filters (which basically give can tell you if a value is NOT in a section of data or not).

Comment: shouldn't `it` be `*it` in the `find` call?

Comment: I'm not exposed or aware to google b-tree and bloom-filters.Can you explain how it can be done?

Comment: Also, comments are not for extended discussions, only for **suggesting improvements**.

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281275/best-way-to-merge-multiple-stl-containers-removing-duplicate-elements).

Comment: @user202729 i googled it and could not find any efficient method.Hope stackoverflow helps!!

Comment: Do you want the vectors to keep the initial order, or any order is ok?

Comment: I read your comment as "I can google b-tree and bloom-filter, but I don't want to do that", that's not nice. What did you want to say?

Comment: With respect to the OP, I think they are assuming google is a noun, not a verb in "google b-tree data-structures and bloom-filters". It is easy to appear rude in English, particularly if it's not your first language.

Comment: Also, is there any special restriction? For general data the method linked above is the best. In cases where one vector is very small, there are other methods.

Comment: @Bathsheba Good point...

Comment: I am in favor of closing this question until it is properly scoped. There is at least 5 questions asking for narrowing or clarification. It's pretty impossible to answer in it's current form. 
Also, (IMHO part) it's going to be too broad. This is basically asking for intro to big data or databases.

Answer (score 4):

First, I hope you either, asking it just hypothetically, to find the "best algorithm" for a problem, or, you are talking about much larger data-sets.

For the amount of data you have, it is not worth thinking about optimizations like this.

In answer to  your question:

This really depends of how many constraints you have on your vectors.
If you know they are sorted, this is easy to solve with one iteration over the two vectors.
If you know they are unique, you probably want to use set.

if you know nothing, you may be tempted to still use set, just as temporary data structure, for faster lookup. This may, or may not be faster in real-world, due to locality

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, I think you're using the wrong tool for the job. It would be better to use a structure that supported uniqueness inherently, like a std::set. Using a vector means the complexity of checking for the existence of a value in your list is O(n) (linearly proportional to the size of the list), while using a std::set would get you O(log(n)) complexity - which is much better - as std::sets are usually based on [red/black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

If you really insist on doing it with vectors, and they're not sorted, then you're in the worst of all worlds and you'll end up doing a "Cartesian-Product Join" where the number of comparisons you're doing is the product of the number of rows in each set (i.e. 5x100 = 500 in this case). When the vectors are small, that may be acceptable, but as they grow it will quickly kill your performance.

So, one way out of this is to:

- Sort your vectors
- Perform a [sort merge join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort-merge_join) on the result.

However, be careful in your choice of sorting algorithm too as that can also be expensive and ideally store the sorted result and maintain the vectors in sorted order. If you're re-sorting all the time, that will also kill performance.

(Or, go back to the top of this answer and reconsider your decision to stick with a vector...)